# To use a user defined entity in SillyNameMaker

Tags: dialogflow-es, entities

I've just done the sample project SillyNameMaker and now I am trying to add one my own defined entity, saying 'weekday' (Mon., Tue., Wed., Thu., Fri., Sat. and Sun.). The entity is created and set in proper way. However, I cannot get this 'weekday' value in the index.js. Here is my code snippet:

```
'use strict';

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('make_name', (conv, {color, number, weekday}) => {
conv.close(`Alright, buddy, your silly name is ${color} ${number} ! ` +
    `I hope you like it. See you next ${weekday}.`);
});

exports.sillyNameMaker = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

After 'red', '4' and 'Monday' are said, the response always gets "Alright, buddy, your silly name is red 4 ! I hope you like it. See you next weekday". There is no 'Monday'.

Can someone help me to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: what have you added in dialogflow because without it can solve the issue? 
share link of screenshot

Comment: hope these helpful

https://i.imgur.com/u89sW63.png
https://i.imgur.com/JtIzQoZ.png
https://i.imgur.com/GYXy2jc.png
https://i.imgur.com/nOCVGnz.png

Comment: i suggest you first check for a response in default simulator without webhook.
Are you getting all parameters?

Comment: Without webhook and my experiments text response using "These are what I got: '$color', '$number', '$geocountry' and '$weekday'", I got the correct parameters except 'weekday'. 
'88', 'yellow', 'japan' and 'monday' are said, the result shows 
   "These are what I got: 'yellow', '88', 'Japan' and 'weekday'."
Where do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Your weekday entity is set up incorrectly. Here's your screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Dialogflow entity page]

You've created an entity with the value "weekday" and the synonyms "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", etc. This means that if the user says "Sunday", Dialogflow will recognize it and map it to the value "weekday", which will be sent to your webhook.

The correct configuration is in the following screenshot:

[image]

You don't need to define any synonyms; just a list of possible entity values.